# Robot footprint fluctuates when 2d pose estimate is applied on RVIz

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
So I am new to ROS and I am facing a major headache for the past week. Specifically, I am having a problem that is actually shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-A4o0_wJe08). Whenever I set the 2d pose estimate of Robot, the footprint and costmap kind of fluctuates around the map. I am using an amcl node with a static map, so whenever I give a pose estimate the particle cloud changes correctly. Due to this problem it can't estimate an accurate path to the goal node and the path fluctuates as well. My launch file codes are below. Please get me rid of this problem. Thanks!

---

### Trajectory Planner

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.4
  min_vel_x: 0.2
  max_rotational_vel: 0.5
  max_vel_theta: 1.5
  min_vel_theta: -1.5
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.25
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.7
  escape_vel: -0.25
  acc_lim_theta: 0.3
  acc_lim_x: 0.5
  acc_lim_Y: 0.07
  holonomic_robot: false
  meter_scoring: true
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
```

---

### Local costmap params

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 2
  height: 2
  resolution: 0.025
```

---

### Global costmap params

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  width: 15
  height: 15
  resolution: 0.1
```

---

### Costmap common params

```
obstacle_range: 5.0
raytrace_range: 6.0

max_obstacle_height: 0.2
min_obstacle_height: 0.05

robot_radius: 0.20
inflation_radius: 0.15

transform_tolerance: 1.0
map_type: costmap
cost_scaling_factor: 100

map_topic: /map
subscribe_to_updates: true

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan , marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

### My Robot Configuration File

```
<launch>

<rosparam param="ticks_meter">17825</rosparam>
<node pkg="differential_drive" type="diff_tf.py" name="odometry" output="screen">
        <remap from="lwheel" to="left_encoder" />
        <remap from="rwheel" to="right_encoder" />
        <rosparam param="base_width">0.195</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="odom_frame_id" subst_value="True" > "/odom" </rosparam>
        <rosparam param="base_frame_id" subst_value="True"> "/base_link" </rosparam>
        <rosparam param="global_frame_id" subst_value="True"> "/map" </rosparam>
        <rosparam param="rate">50</rosparam>
</node>
<node pkg="differential_drive" type="pid_velocity.py" name="lpid">
        <remap from="wheel" to= "left_encoder"/>
        <remap from="motor_cmd" to= "left_pwm"/>
        <remap from="wheel_vtarget" to= "left_target"/>
        <remap from="wheel_vel" to= "left_actual"/>
        <rosparam param="Kp">480</rosparam >
        <rosparam param="Ki">250</rosparam >
        <rosparam param="Kd">18</rosparam >
        <rosparam param="out_min">-255</rosparam >
        <rosparam param="out_max">255</rosparam >
        <rosparam param="rate">40</rosparam >
        <rosparam param="timeout_ticks">4</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="rolling_pts">5</rosparam>
</node>
<node pkg="differential_drive" type="pid_velocity.py" name="rpid">
        <remap from="wheel" to="right_encoder"/>
        <remap from="motor_cmd" to="right_pwm"/>
        <remap from="wheel_vtarget" to="right_target"/>
        <remap from="wheel_vel" to="right_actual"/>
        <rosparam param="Kp">480</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="Ki">250</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="Kd">18</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="out_min">-255</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="out_max">255</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="rate">40</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="timeout_ticks">4</rosparam>
        <rosparam param="rolling_pts">5</rosparam>
</node>
<node pkg="differential_drive" type="twist_to_motors.py" name="twist" output="screen">
        <remap from="twist" to="cmd_vel"/>
        <remap from="lwheel_vtarget" to="left_target"/>
        <remap from="rwheel_vtarget" to="right_target"/>
        <rosparam param="base_weight">0.195</rosparam>
</node>
<node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="serial_node">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
        <param name="baud" value="57600"/>
</node>

#<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_transform" args="0 0 0.14 0 0 0 /map /odom 100"
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_transform" args="0 0 0.14 0 0 0 base_link laser 100"
</launch>
```

---

### Move Base Launch

```
<launch>

   <master auto="start"/>
<arg name="map_file" default=" /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/provide_map/maps/swiftmap.yaml"/>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)">
    <param name="frame_id" type="str" value="map"/>
</node>
<include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch"/>
   <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="controller_frequency" type="double" value="6.0"/>
    <param name="planner_frequency" type="double" value="0.5"/>
 </node>


</launch>
```

---

### AMCL Launch File##

```
<launch>
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
  <!-- translation std dev, m -->
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom"/>
  <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="global_frame_id" value="/map"/>
  <param name="use_map_topic" value="true"/>
  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340683/robot-footprint-fluctuates-when-2d-pose-estimate-is-applied-on-rviz./) by [aneessameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/50514/aneessameer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be due to an inconsistency in the TF tree such multiple tf broadcasters for the same frame. Can you post the output of

```
rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree
```

to confirm that everything is okay in that regard?

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aneessameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/50514/aneessameer/) on 2020-03-04**:
Thanks for answering. The problem was that there were multiple tf_broadcasters for the same frame.